# How to use getBounds() function with React-Leaflet

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet

I've got a map created with React-Leaflet.
To start my map, I've some latitude and longitude predefined, but my users can navigate through the map and when they do this, I want to get the latitude and longitude of the bounds to search new locations based on this.

So, on Leaflet.js we have the `getBounds()` function. I'm trying to figure out how to use the same with this React component, without success. Somebody know how? Thank's!